# TextBox loosing focus when displaying popup

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I try to implement something similar to Intellisense: while the user enters text in a (WinForms) TextBox, I'd like to display suggestions.

Currently, I'm doing something like this in the TextChanged-EventHandler of the TextBox:

```
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.Items.Add(new DataItem() { Id = "1", DisplayText = "Abc" });
        lb.Items.Add(new DataItem() {Id = "2", DisplayText = "Abuiaec"});


        ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
        popup.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(lb);
        host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Items.Add(host);
        popup.Show(this, Point.Empty);
```

However, as soon as the popup comes up, the TextBox loses its focus. The popup does not get focus - it seems like the focus disappears completely.

What can I do against this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you using `ToolStripMenu` , do you have any specific reason?, you can use `AutoComplete` feature to display the items on textbox

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Because I'm going to replace the listbox later by some custom listbox which will display bigger and more complex control for each suggestion.

Comment: Jerking the focus away in an event handler is always dangerous, you'll have to delay that by using Control.BeginInvoke().  That won't be the end of trouble, a dropdown doesn't like losing the focus since it uses it to automatically collapse again.  Dynamically creating and disposing a plain list box is the proper approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `textbox.Select()` at the end to give focus to textbox.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. I had tried .Focus() which doesn't have any effect either.